# Error in webhook subscription api

Tags: azure-active-directory, outlook-restapi

I have followed the instruction for using the Outlook REST APIs [webhook push notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/webhooks).

I want push notification from the calendar for creating, updating and deleting `event` entities. I have called below request:

```http
Method Type: Post

URL: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/subscriptions
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization : Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN

Request Body :
{

"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
"Resource": "https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/events",
"NotificationURL": "https://krogerfreshwebhook.ngrok.io/myNotifyClient",  
"ChangeType": "Created",
"ClientState": "MySecretClientStateString"
}
```

But I am getting below error in response header

```http
content-length : 0
date : Mon, 20 Nov 2017 12:58:03 GMT
request-id : 38ac0346-088f-4b43-80b2-32c6cf64b22c
status : 401
www-authenticate : Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", token_types="app_asserted_user_v1 service_asserted_app_v1", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", error="invalid_token",Basic Realm="",Basic Realm="",Basic Realm=""
x-backendhttpstatus : 401, 401
x-beserver : MA1PR01MB0485
x-calculatedbetarget : MA1PR01MB0485.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
x-calculatedfetarget : MA1PR01CU001.internal.outlook.com
x-diaginfo : MA1PR01MB0485
x-feproxyinfo : MA1PR01CA0025.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
x-feserver : MA1PR01CA0025, BM1PR01CA0075
reason="ErrorCode: 'PP_E_RPS_CERT_NOT_FOUND'
```

Message:

```
'Certificate cannot be found. Certificate required for the operation cannot be found.%0d%0a 

Internal error: spRPSTicket->ProcessToken failed. 
Failed to call CRPSDataCryptImpl::UnpackData:Certificate cannot be found. Certificate required for the operation cannot be found.%0d%0a Internal error: Failed to decrypt data. :Failed to get session key. RecipientId=293577. spCache->GetCacheItem returns error.:Cert Name: (null). 
error_category="invalid_msa_ticket"
x-msedge-ref : Ref A: 0C4DE404A07C474FA67DC1A986C2DEA0 Ref B: BOM01EDGE0220 Ref C: 2017-11-20T12:58:03Zenter code here
x-powered-by : ASP.NET
```

Additional Information:

Authorization URL:

```
login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
   ?response_type=code
   &client_id=my_clinet_id
   &redirect_uri=my_redirect_url
   &authorize
   &scope=openid,offline_access,User.ReadWrite,Mail.ReadWrite,Contacts.ReadWrite,Tasks.ReadWrite,Calendars.ReadWrite,Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared,Mail.Send,Group.Read.All,Files.ReadWrite,Files.ReadWrite.All
```

When I call calendar api then it is working fine. It is giving me event list of calendar but when I use the same token for subscription of push notification then it is giving me invalid token error

Comment: This isn't an error with the subscription endpoint, it's an error with your token. Please add how your obtaining the `access token` your sending in your request.

Comment: I got token using below url 

URL :
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
response_type=code&
client_id=my_clinet_id&
redirect_uri=my_redirect_url&
authorize&scope=openid,offline_access,User.ReadWrite,Mail.ReadWrite,Contacts.ReadWrite,Tasks.ReadWrite,
Calendars.ReadWrite,Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared,Mail.Send,Group.Read.All,Files.ReadWrite,Files.ReadWrite.All


..  When I call calender api then it is working fine. It is giving me event list of calender but when I use the same token for subscription of push notification then it is giving me invalid token error

Comment: Which URI are you calling to get calendars?

Comment: I am using endpoint "/me/events" to get calendar events and I am getting all my calendar events. but I am not able to set push notification for calendar events.

Comment: Since you're not using Graph, you need to prefix your scopes with `https://outlook.office.com/` (i.e. `https://outlook.office.com/mail.read`). This tells the system which resource you're requesting the scope for.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I am making following request  

URL : https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/subscriptions  

Request Headers :-  

Content-Type : application/json  

Authorization : Bearer TOKEN  

Request Body :-  

`{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.OutlookServices.PushSubscription",
  "Resource": "https://outlook.office.com/me/events",
  "NotificationURL": "https://dev-test.salesmate.io/kroogerwebhook/myNotifyClient",  
  "ChangeType": "Created",
  "ClientState": "MySecretClientStateString"
}`

Comment: Did you try the URL prefix on your scopes?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Yes, I have tried but getting the same error.